# How did Tony Stark create this?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

How did Tony Stark create an Infinity Gauntlet in *Avengers: Endgame*?
Is it not a given that the Gauntlet must be enchanted or else the dwarves would not be required to create it?

Comment: [Asked and answered on SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/210885/98028)

Answer (score 8):

Magic is just advanced science.

> As Thor explains to MCU lynchpin Jane Foster in his first movie, magic is just sufficiently-advanced science. Tony, presumably with Bruce's help, figured out how to make an Infinity Gauntlet from first principles.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[How could Tony Stark make this in Endgame? - SFF.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/210885/how-could-tony-stark-make-this-in-endgame)</sub>

Iron Man is smart, really smart, presumably, he just figured it out (with some help from Bruce).

Comment: Yep, you're right! 

"Your ancestors called it magic and you call it science. Well, I come from a place where they are one and the same thing."
―Thor to Jane Foster[src]